# Using Tile Index in QGIS Web Client?

Tags: qgis-web-client

I have many aerial photos. I created a tile_index with gdaltindex. Now I would like to display the aerial photos of the tile_index in qgis-web-client.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

A raw solution would be creating a polygon grid from your tiles, getting the id into the grid polygons, and only displaying the labels in your qgis project which has now one layer in plus.